# Replacing and modifying a string

Tags: c#, replace

I want to replace some characters with others i have asked a question like this before here and they recommend to use function Replace,but when i used Replace it falls in specific condition when i try replace chars with another char it removes another char that is also in a string and i don't want to remove.here is my code for more clarification

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < words[i].Length; j++)
    {
        if (j + 2 == words[i].Length)
            break;

        if (words[i][j] == words[i][j + 2] && words[i][j + 1] == '0')
        {
            words[i] = words[i].Replace(words[i][j + 1].ToString(), string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

if my string was "a1010" according to my code the final string should be a110 but the output is a11,i wonder why it removes the final 0??

Comment: what is a WORDS ? This code doesn't compile if I assume the WORDS is a string "a1010".

Comment: I find it hard to answer when I can't even begin to understand the purpose or application...

Comment: Is your goal to remove the first zero in a string of text?

Comment: What is the actual problem, in English, that you want to solve?  Do you want to remove the first 0?  The second numeric digit?  The 3rd character?

Comment: There is an algorithm called soundex if i have 2 characters and there is 0 charcter, i should remove the last 2 chars like a1010 the answer should be a10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 words[i] = words[i].Replace(words[i][j + 1].ToString(), string.Empty);
```

basically resolves to...

```
 words[i] = words[i].Replace("0", "");
```

(at least in the particular iteration you are describing)

which is replacing all 0's in your string with empty string.  If you know the exact index of the character you want to remove you can just do this...

```
words[i].Remove(j + 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

The `.Replace` will replace all occurrences of a given character with the character specified for replacement.  This is why both occurrences of 0 have been removed.

Since you are finding the letter you want to replace, try using `Remove` instead and then break out of your loop so you don't remove the second occurrence as well.

Comment: replace will only replace the first occurrence unless you specify /g with a regex

Comment: Uncle Iroh - he's referring to `String.Replace`, not a regex replace.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
words[i] = words[i].Replace(words[i][j + 1].ToString(), string.Empty);
```

replaces *all instances* of the character at position `j+1` in word `i` with the emtpty string. In your example, that means *all* `0`s are removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the first occurrence using this:

```
public static string Replace(string Word, string oldChar, string newChar)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Word.Length; i++)
    {
        string aux = "" + Word[i];
        if (aux.Equals(oldChar))
        {
            Word = Word.Remove(i, 1);
            Word = Word.Insert(i, newChar);

            return Word;
        }
    }
    return Word;
}
```